# Cannot display more than two items

Tags: html, css, web, rows

I'm making a webpage and for one part of it I want to display three objects in one row. The best I could do is make 2 of them display by using `width:100%`.

Does anyone have any tips i can try so it shows `3/4`? At the moment I have 5 items, it goes 2 per row. The items i'm using are made as a list.

**View in Browser:**

[image: 2 Items]

---

**My CSS:**

[image: css that I have]

Comment: Please add your code to the question (real code, not screen grabs of the code)

Comment: Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you dont provide any code nor any more details about your framework

you can divide columns equally like below

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
}
.container div{
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px; 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, but remember there are entire frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), and [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) (to name a few) that make this easier, and they come with their own "three columns" classes, and any other variation of a twelve column grid you can have, from one through 12. A framework comes with a lot of other features that you might not need, though, so consider this if you go the framework route.

But if you simply want three columns in a row, try this:

```css
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200x;
  }

.row .onethird {
width: 33%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="onethird">THING ONE</div>
<div class="onethird">THING TWO</div>
<div class="onethird">THING THREE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A caveat is you need to use the viewport metatag in the head of your html document in order to start doing responsive stuff with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ul.products {width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;} /* adjust as needed */
 ul.products li {float: left; width: 33.3%; width: calc(100% / 3); margin: 0; padding: 0;} /* the calculation is for browsers that support it. The 33.3% is for the browsers that don't. */
 ul.products:after {clear: left; display: table; content: ''} /* always clear your floats */
```